# Allocate a big matrix

Tags: r, ehcache-bigmemory

I'm using the **bigmemory** package. I want to calculate w. My v length is 478000 and k length is 240500. The two matrix multiplication is w very large.

I run the code by loop, but it still is running and is not finished yet and I don't know if will give me the result or not.

I tried to calculate it without the for loop, but I got and error. Please any help to correct my code to make it fast.

```
v <-read.big.matrix('v.dat',type='double')
k <-read.big.matrix('k.dat',type='double')
m=length(v);
n=length(k);
for(i in 1:m)
{
    for(j in 1:n)
    {
       w[i,j] = 2 * cos(dt * v[i] * k[j]) - 2
    }
}
```

How I can define w before the loop because the size of w is very large I couldn't do like `w <- matrix(nr,ncol)`.

Answer (score 2):

Preallocating a matrix can be done like this:

```
m = matrix(rep(0, number_or_rows*number_of_columns), 
     number_of_rows, number_of_columns))
```

This creates a matrix with the amount of rows and columns defined in the variables `number_of_rows` and `number_of_columns`, filled initially with all 0.

What is probably going to be a problem is that because `w` is equal in size to `v` and `k`, you might very well run into memory issues when filling `w`. You could solve this by also using a `bigmemory` matrix for `w`, or running your analysis in chunks.

Comment: w should be 478000  by 240500.How i can allocate 1TB I got error regarding the too many elements to allocate

Answer (score 1):

agstudy is on the right track, but you could use `outer` here, as

`w <- outer(v,k,FUN=function(x,y) 2*cos(x*y)-2 )`

```
v<-runif(10)
k<-runif(10)
m=length(v);
n=length(k);
w<-matrix(nr=m,nc=n)
for(i in 1:m)
{
    for(j in 1:n)
    {
       w[i,j] = 2 * cos( v[i] * k[j]) - 2
    }
}

ww <- outer(v,k,function(x,y) 2*cos(x*y)-2)
```

Test:  ww-w is a matrix of zeroes.

Comment: @agstudy I just tried it and it worked exactly fine. See edit.

Comment: +1 Yes it works..  for some reasons I tested your code with 2 matrix not vectors..

Comment: but my problem here w i can not define it as w<- matrix(nr=m, nc=n) since w is very lage matrix it works with me in small matrix but i need it to work with large matrix. My w here is 478000 by 240500

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'big.matrix"-class constructors, and since you are obviously exceeding RAM resources, it would appear necessary that you define it as a "filebacked.big.matrix"

```
w <- filebacked.big.matrix( m, n , # additional arguments to allocate files and dims
                           )
```

See the last example in:

```
 help(big.matrix, package=bigmemory)
```

Comment: I did it but the loop here didn't want to stop and the code was runnig from week ago till now and didn't get any results.

Comment: Did "it"? You mean you looked at the help page or you mean you executed similar code? You are not going to succeed with a regular matrix that is filling up virtual memory. Have you considered the possiblity this is just 'too big' for your computer?

Comment: I mean I tried to run this code for the big matrix but it didn't work with me I don't know what is the problem :       library('bigmemory')
        library('irlba')
        v <-read.big.matrix('v.dat',type='double')
        k <-read.big.matrix('k.dat',type='double')
        m=length(v);
        n=length(k);
        w<-filebacked.big.matrix(m,n,type="double",backingfile="w.bin",descriptorfile="w.desc")
        
         for(i in 1:m)
        {

               for(j in 1:n)
               {
                       w[i,j]=2*cos(0.001*v[i]*k[j])-2
                }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this using R vectorization feature:

```
for(i in 1:m)
{
  w[i] = 2 * cos(dt * v[i] * k) - 2 # I compute n terms here
}
```

Comment: I have to define w .I got this error message object 'w' not found. w here should be 478000 by 240500. my problem is in the memory